# Socket Error delphi

Tags: delphi, windows-server, indy

Выставил серверное приложение на Win 2012 сервер в DMZ.

Приложение написано на Delphi Berlin 10.1.2 c использованием Indy.

При подключении через домашний WiFi приложение откликается на запросы клиентской части.

При попытке сделать запрос через интернет 3G, Yota получаю сообщение

> Error: Project XXX raised exception class EIdSockedError with message 'Socket Error $ 53 Software caused connection abort'.

Другое приложение выдает: Socket error #10060

Что то с таймаутом судя по всему, но не понятно с каким.

Никто не сталкивался?

Comment: 10060 - означает таймаут.  Проверяйте настройки сети. Если подключение через прокси провертьте ping прокси. Если нет - приходит ли IP DNS сервера? Даёт ли ответ DNS? Дает ли ответ IP который выдал DNS?

Comment: покажите айпи адрес "сервера", куда подключаетесь.  Если боитесь, можете последние цифры (после последней точки) заменить звездочкой.

Comment: До сервера Ping проходит. Не проходит telnet (через 3G). Адрес машинки 95.84.*.*

Comment: а тогда все просто - нужно на роутере порты проборосить или разбанить фаервол. DMZ как бы подразумевает некую проброску, но мало чего там в роутере.

Comment: Собственно, сервер в DMZ, порт 3000 переадресован на роутере. Пробовал убирать firewall на модеме. Маштину перегружал. Не понимаю.